# wooCommerce login redirect based on cart not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is my need

If User not logged in and cart is empty: Then redirect user to login and then my account.
If User not logged in and cart has product: Then redirect user to login and after login redirect to checkout.
Here is the code I tried

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woocommerce_custom_redirections');

function woocommerce_custom_redirections() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() )
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );

if( is_user_logged_in() && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_account_page() )
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
```

}

First case is working fine, but in my second case it is not redirecting to the cart page instead it is getting redirected to the current page means if we checkout from home page it will redirect to home page after login.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0
```

Comment: Tried, but no change. Still its not redirecting to the cart page instead to home page.